# firebase authentication limited to one provider

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to limit the Authentication to my Firebase project to only one specific provider. Is it possible to deny authentication for email addresses other than @specific.provider.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow only users with a certain mail provider access to you project, you need to create a method that can check the email provider for you. Let say you want to restrict users to create an account only if their provider is Google. An email address which belongs to Google looks like this: `name@gmail.com`

So, you need to verify which are the characters after `@` symbol. If those characters are `equals` to `gmail.com` let the user create his account, otherwise `Toast` a message.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can set up your sign in method in Firebase console like attached image. If you want to deny authentication for email/password just disable it in the console

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want ?

Comment: i want to allow only users with a certain mail provider access to my project. for example @this.com. so i don't want users with gmail, gmx, yahoo or other providers being able to sign up to my project. it should guarantee that only users from my university are able to see the content. they all have the same mail provider, so i thought that might be the easiest way of accomplishing the task.